# Mysql authorization on a table or a column

Tags: mysql, authorization

I am wondering if it's possible to set a mysql user to have read access to only a certain table or column in a database?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it at a fine grained level for databases using GRANT.  See

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked for all other columns but not the primary key column. Do you know why?